# How to block api requests from web browsers and tools like cURL?

Tags: web-services, rest, security, restful-authentication

I am currently making a server that serves API requests to mobile clients. I want to somehow block web browsers or tools like cURL from making requests to my API. Is that possible? If it is, what is the most secure and efficient way of doing that?

Comment: How about using password / secret token based authentication to block unwanted requests?

Comment: @gaganshera I have an authentication API that gives an auth token once the user logs in, but you could log in using cURL (and even the web browser)...

Answer (score 0):

Your server cannot really block individual curl requests. However, your server can refuse serving requests that it doesn't want to.
To explain it a bit better, suppose your mobile sends in an HTTP request. Any curl request can be made to mimic that exact mobile request, making it look like it came from your mobile (by sending the same headers, auth params etc). Your server doesn't see curl, it just sees the HTTP request.
You might try blocking requests with user agent string that looks like it comes from curl, but this won't be of much use; as I mentioned, curl can be used to mimic any HTTP request.

Coming to your comment

> I have an authentication API that gives an auth token once the user logs in, but you could log in using cURL (and even the web browser)

If you have an https server, your requests are safe from getting hijacked, since the user can only read his own requests, not the ones sent by other devices. So you don't really need to block curl requests.